# Mocking a pure virtual function in gtest and testing with expect_call

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, mocking, googletest

I am trying to test a function call from another function using gtest.
A simplified version of the header and cpp files are:
**Sample.h**

```
class Sample {
public:
   Sample();
   ~Sample();
   void funcA();
protected:
   virtual void funcB()=0;
};
```

In **Sample.cpp** the funcA calls funcB.

```
funcA() {
   funcB();
}
```

The code works as expected but writing its unit test fails. The example of unit test I wrote is as following:

**testSample.cpp**

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "Sample.h"

class SampleMock : public Sample {
public:
    SampleMock(): SampleMock(){};
    virtual ~SampleMock(){};
    MOCK_METHOD0(funcB, void());
};

class SampleTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        sample = new SampleMock();
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {
        delete sample;
    }
    Sample* sample;
};

TEST_F(SampleTest, Test1)
{
    SampleMock tempObj;
    EXPECT_CALL(tempObj, funcB);
    sample->funcA();
}
}
```

I want to run a test and make sure that on the invocation of funcA, funcB is called. But running this test throws the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Sample::funcA()", referenced from:
      SampleTest_Test1_Test::TestBody() in testSample.o
  "Sample::Sample(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      SampleMock::SampleMock() in testSample.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show full error message.

Comment: The syntax in your code is wrong: `void funcA;` `funcA {  funcB();
}`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin edited that here. It was correct in the original code. Also attached the full error message

Comment: Could you please provide the full cmake output message here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code example you show:

You are inheriting from Sample, so change this:

```
~Sample();
```

to:

```
virtual ~Sample() = default;
```

---

Also in the `SampleMock` class, the constructor is delegating to itself:

```
SampleMock(): SampleMock(){};
```

You probably meant to:

```
SampleMock(): Sample(){};
```

---

```
SampleMock* sample; // instead of Sample* sample
```

Regarding your test, `EXPECT_CALL` expects a mock. I'm not entirely sure what the intent is in the test. Anyway, this should get you passed compilation:

Make funcA virtual: `virtual void funcA()`

Mocked class becomes like this

```
class SampleMock : public Sample {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, funcB, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(void, funcA, (), (override));
};
```

`SampleTest` :

```
class SampleTest : public ::testing::Test {
public:
  // ...
  SampleMock* sample;
};
```

And the test will once called with funcA delegate it to the base, and we expect that funcB also be called.

```
TEST_F(SampleTest, Test1)
{
  EXPECT_CALL(*sample, funcA).WillOnce([this]() {
    sample->Sample::funcA();
  });

  EXPECT_CALL(*sample, funcB).Times(1);

  sample->funcA();
}
```

Comment: This works. But why are we adding the first expect_call?